# Fast solution for a nonlinear system of 3 equations of degree 3?

Tags: non-linear-systems

I have a nonlinear system of 3 equations with 27 constants and 3 unknowns `x, y, z`

```
X = x*(uX1*x^2+vX1*x+wX1) + y*(uX2*y^2+vX2*y+wX2) + z*(uX3*z^2+vX3*z+wX3)
Y = x*(uY1*x^2+vY1*x+wY1) + y*(uY2*y^2+vY2*y+wY2) + z*(uY3*z^2+vY3*z+wY3)
Z = x*(uZ1*x^2+vZ1*x+wZ1) + y*(uZ2*y^2+vZ2*y+wZ2) + z*(uZ3*z^2+vZ3*z+wZ3)
```

The constants `u, v, w` (named according to the components, for example `uX1, vX1, wX1, uY1, vY1, wY1, uZ1, vZ1, wZ1`) are the parameters of polynomials of degree 3 that match the behavior of electronic components. They were obtained by curve fitting. Each polynomial is equal to 0 at the origin. Here's an example of the typical behavior of the components (data points are in black, fitted curves in RGB):

[image: Behavior of components]

Is there any method/algorithm that resolves this system for real-time applications? Or that finds exact solutions?

Only real and positive solutions are needed.

Comment: ...30 constants...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is best asked on SO tagged with your favorite language. Probably not on Math.

Comment: This could usefully be asked on the [Scientific Computing Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There are exist algorithms for solving systems of ordinary differential equations, like [Runge-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods).

There are also many implementations of these algorithms for various software - in R, MatLab, [python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html), etc.